# Are iCloud Tabs for Safari end to end encrypted?

Tags: cloud-storage, end-to-end-encryption, apple, safari

I [see](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202303) that iCloud bookmarks are not covered under end-to-end-encryption on the iCloud security overview, but no mention is made of iCloud Tabs, which seems even more important. Are Tabs stored merely using server side encryption and hence Apple is technically able to provide your open tabs to a third party?